# Submit multiple files with MVC and Safari

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, safari

I need to submit multiple files with safari.

I'm using https://github.com/weixiyen/jquery-filedrop but it does not support Safari, so I'm trying to use an iframe:

```
<input type="file" id="browse" name='files[]' multiple />

<form id="formUp" name="formUp" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="sessionId" id="sessionId" value="9101" />
    <iframe style="position: absolute; opacity: 0;" allowTransparency="true" id="iframe" src='' frameborder="0" width="0" height="0" name="iframe"></iframe>
</form>
```

The input file is outside of the form because where it's located, it's already inside a form.

MVC:

```
public virtual ActionResult Create(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files, int sessionId)
    {
        foreach (HttpPostedFileBase file in files)
        {
        }
     }
```

Javascript:

```
function safariLoad()
{
   $("#browse").change(function ()
   {
     $("#formUp").attr("action", "/SessionPicture/Create");
     $("#sessionId").val($("#Session_Id").val());
     $("#formUp").attr("target", "iframe");
     $("#formUp").submit();
   }
```

The problem is that I always get null in the files from MVC side.

Any help?

Thanks.

Comment: You should access the files through the Request.Files-property, not as a parameter to your action

Comment: Hi, thanks, and how do you think I can combine both to have a more cross-browser solution? Thanks

Comment: They are unrelated. If the plugin does not support Safari, you should either look in to modifying the plugin or use a different one. But this unrelated to how MVC accepts files. It doesn't by parameters in the action-method but by accessing the files-property on the request-object

Comment: Any plug-in or example that you could suggest for this? Thanks